# CodeIgniter, llamar una funcion de un controlador a otro

Tags: php, codeigniter

un saludo de mi parte, tengo una duda con CodeIgniter, y es la siguiente:

resulta que estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema de multas para vehículo, algo simple para entender la naturaleza del framework, en donde tengo 2 tablas en una base de datos, (vehiculo y multa), esta a su vez tengo 2 modelos(VehiculoModel y MultaModel), que son accedido por los 2 controladores(Vehiculo y Multa), respetando la filosofía de este framework, ya hice el apartado de registrar , guardar y consultar vehiculos, en controlador Vehiculo, con sus vistas necesarias, ahora la duda es la siguiente.........Estoy tratando de llamar desde el controlador Multa una función que esta en el controlador Vehiculo, que es para obtener los datos del vehículo y cargarlo en la vista que se encargara de registrar la multa, como se puede hacer esta operación?

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, te invito a agregar codigo de ejemplo para que sea mas clara tu duda y te podamos ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tratas de hacer no es compatible con el comportamiento del sistema MVC. Si deseas ejecutar una acción de otro controlador, tienes que redirigir al usuario a la página que deseas (es decir, la función del controlador que consume la url).

Si deseas una funcionalidad común, debes construir una librería que sea utilizada en los dos controladores.

Se puede suponer que quieres construir tu aplicación un poco modular. (Es decir, re-utilizar la salida del método de un controlador en otros métodos de controlador.) La forma más sencilla es utilizar una librería para construir "controles" comunes (es decir, cargar el modelo, renderizar la vista en una cadena). Luego, puedes retornar esta cadena y pasarla a la vista del otro controlador.

Por ejemplo:

```
$string_view = $this->load->view('someview', array('data'=>'stuff'), true);
```

Tambien puedes revisar el siguiente link que tiene información de como hacerlo mediante rutas.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165895/how-to-load-a-controller-from-another-controller-in-codeigniter

**EDITADO PREGUNTA EN EL COMENTARIO**

Para llamar un modelo en la librería podrías hacer algo así:

```
public function util(){
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $CI->load->model('VehiculoModel');
      $result = $CI->prueba_model->getVehiculo();
      return $result;
```

}

Comment: Hola Juan Pinzo, gracias por tu respuesta, creo que ya estoy entendiendo, pero tengo otra pregunta, hay alguna forma de crear una librería que este cargue el modelo que este caso VehiculoModel?, cuando tenga tiempo veo el link que compartiste, Gracias

Comment: Ok, de nada, ya edite la respuesta en base a tu pregunta, si te sirvió marcala como respuesta a tu problema, así otros usuarios pueden encontrar útil la respuesta

Comment: Hola Juan, muchas gracias me ayudo mucho, era el único detalle que tenia, muchas gracias.